# How do I prevent the WiFi from dropping when an external monitor DPMS-es?

Tags: wifi, power-management

Near as I can tell, when macOS puts the monitors to sleep due to inactivity, the WiFi drops.

Can it … not?

(Note: we're plugged in the entire time. I'm not sleeping the laptop, I'm not closing the lid, I'm standing up to stretch my legs and coming back to find anything that required Internet has died because I was gone about long enough for the screens to turn off.)